# Control a web browser from php

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I'm mainly using `curl` to access some website data from `php` but I often asked myself if it existed another solution if a day, too much javascript code (for example) blocked my attempts.
Then is there a `gecko/js` box, a kind of headless web browser that can be controled by php, and the final dom accessed ?

Comment: Not from pure php. If the remote site is built with javascript, with DOM events, then it needs to be executed with javascript. But you can control and create node js scripts from php, https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer

Comment: There are many headless browser options, did you investigate them? Or do you mean something else?